# Should version specific tags be created for libraries

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently asked (and answered) this question: [BsonSerializationException when serializing a Dictionary to BSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28111846/885318)

It's a question about a new version (v2.0) of the MongoDB driver for C#. This new version is pretty much a re-write and it comes with a new API (though it's possible to use the old API using deprecated methods).

The new version is very different than the old one and I believe it will cause many version specific questions like this recent one: [Using SetFields with MongoDb C# driver 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28541082/885318)

I've only seen version specific tags for programming languages and frameworks. Should I create a version specific tag for this library as well?

Comment: The same principles that apply to programming languages and frameworks also apply to libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Personally we should try to encorage the OP to express the version they are using in the question.

The OP, or community, should then edit the question if it turns out the same problem arises in multiple versions, and of course edit the accepted answer appropriately.

I expect that these types of questions will become community wiki. And are likely most useful for work arounds to known limitations / bugs.
On the other hand if it is a known bug then editing to include a link to the bug would be best, and the accepted answer should have a link to the solution as posted in the same bug (if one exists).

That at least is my opinion.

David.

Comment: Half-agree; this describes the specific situation of a major version upgrade which basically turns it into a completely different tool with completely different semantics. I'd say that actually makes it useful to be able to isolate the new from the legacy with a specific tag.